# What is the average distance of two different types of molecules of different concentrations in solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Concerning the simplest approximation for intermolecular distance in solution:
$d=(\frac{10^{24}}{cN_A})^{1/3}=1.18c^{−1/3}$
This applies for one type of molecule in solution. But, how to account for two different molecules A and B of different concentrations?
My case: I have molecule A of 0,4 uM and molecule B of 16x0,4 = 6,4 uM. The average distance A-A is therefore determined as 160 nm, average distance of B-B as 63,5 nm and average distance of any two molecules as 62,3 nm.
Is it possible to approximate the average distance of A-B as a weighed average of A-A and B-B, therefore (160+16*62,3)/17 = 69,2 nm, since any given molecule is 16-times more likely to be of type B than type A?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What exactly are we talking about, to begin with? Is it the average distance from A to the nearest B, or from B to the nearest A? These two are going to be _different_.

Comment: In this case, what matters is the average distance between A (the molecule of lower concentration) to B. Thanks a lot!